# React native flatlist, not updating correctly when deleting element from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im having a problem with a Flatlist from React Native. Im not a professional in React, but I kinda know my way.

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.rules}
      renderItem={({ item, index}) => (
        <CodeRow
          text={item.text}
          key={index}
          numList={index}
          onTextUpdate={this.updateRules.bind(this)}
          onDeletePress={this.alertDeleteRule.bind(this)}
        />
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item._id}
    />
```

When deleting an Element from the rules array in state, it deletes correctly from the array, but graphically in the flatlist, it doesnt matter if i delete the first, second, last, it always removes visually the last element from the list, but it stays in the state array.

```
deleteRule(numList){
        console.log("Selected Delete: ",numList);
        console.log("antes", this.state.rules);
        let ruleArray = this.state.rules;
        ruleArray.splice(numList, 1);
        console.log("despues", ruleArray);
        this.setState({ rules: ruleArray });   
    }
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the keys from the components, but im really stuck here. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `_id` of your items into the `key` prop of your item's component:

```
<FlatList 
    data={this.state.rules}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <CodeRow
            text={item.text}
            key={item._id}
            numList={index}
            onTextUpdate={this.updateRules.bind(this)}
            onDeletePress={this.alertDeleteRule.bind(this)}
        />
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item._id}
/>
```